# strtotime for 00 case

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I echo the value of strtotime of current date with 00.30pm value but it gives me blank result. Can anyone guide me why it not showing the value. Or is there any way to get value of

echo strtotime('03/23/2017 00:30am');

Comment: No need to add am pm just consider value with 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it will work:

Format: [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php)

```
echo strtotime('03/23/2017 00:30a.m.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your format is wrong.

Correct is

```
 echo strtotime('03/23/2017 00:30');
```

or

```
echo strtotime('03/23/2017 12:30am');
```

Comment: Is php interpreer understands am or pm if we did not mention it ?

Comment: AM, PM needs only in 12 hrs time format not in 24 hrs

Answer (score 1):

Please check with following code

```
$dateString = "03/23/2017 00:30am";
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y h:ia', $dateString);
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $loc_strto_time = strtotime($newDateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it will solve  your problem. you are appending am within strtotime thats why it is not resuting anything.

```
echo date("jS F, Y h:i:s A", strtotime("03/23/2017 00:30"));
```